# Changing python code, to only import points from dxfs (or to only import lines)?

Tags: pyqgis, import, dxf

edit -  This code no longer works in the new version of QGIS (QGIS 3.0)
If I paste it into the python console it generates a series of requests for the CRS but then imports nothing.
QGIS 3.0 has moved to a newer version of Python and the code I have is incompatible.

How do I edit it to make it work again?

Original question:

I just merged several hundred layers into QGIS which had been imported using this code:-

```
import glob, os
path = "H:/aOsmap/Miltkeyn/2012 ntfs/all/"
for layer in glob.glob(path + "*.dxf"):
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(layer, 'name', 'ogr')
    subLayers = vlayer.dataProvider().subLayers()
    for subLayer in subLayers:
        geom_type = subLayer.split(':')[-1]
        uri = "%s|layername=entities|geometrytype=%s" % (layer, geom_type,)
        dfx_file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(layer))[0]
        layer_name = "%s - %s" % (dfx_file_name,geom_type,)
        sub_vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, layer_name, 'ogr')
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(sub_vlayer)
```

Merging them was difficult because the merge window (vector-merge layers) mixes up the linestring layers and the point layers so selecting just the point layers or just the linestring layers, from about over 600 layers, is laborious and prone to clicking on the wrong layer.

It would be easier and quicker to import all the points from my dxfs in one go and merge those (saving the merged file) and then import all the linestrings from the dxfs and merge those.

However, I don't understand the code so I have no idea what to alter to just select points or just select lines.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: As per the [Tour] chit chat like "please", "thanks", etc should not be included in questions here.

Comment: The tour makes no mention that those words are banned.

In fact, one of the examples of correct usage in the tour INCLUDES the words 'Thank you' so your comment is incorrect in both cases.

Saying please is not chit-chat; it is normal politeness. Excluding it turns a polite request for assistance into a rude demand for an answer.

.

Comment: @PJLightning Thank you for your thoughts on this subject. Please review the "popular" meta post on this subject: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/3021

Comment: Not to barge in @PolyGeo, but some other upvoted answers mention that [please IS allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64811/295637) and don't generate that much noise. If anything, the edit that bumped the question back up to the top was probably *more disruptive* than the please comment at the end.

Comment: @FrankerZ my one word edit should be [taken in context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306523/why-was-the-word-please-removed-from-the-end-of-my-question#comment996517_306523).  I think helping users to understand that SE is not a discussion forum (where social niceties are fine) is important in order to keep questions and answers here clear and crisp.

Comment: @PJLightning those words are not banned but each question here may be read by many thousands of visitors, looking for instant answers, and it can be considered impolite to consume their time, or the volunteered time of potential answerers, reading any words that are included only for social purposes.  You'll see "please" used frequently in temporary comments but not in the Q&As that construct our "Wikipedia" of GIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `if` statement to only allow certain a `geom_type` to be imported. Right after the line `geom_type = subLayer.split(':')[-1]` add:

- For points:

  ```
  if geom_type == 'Point':
  ```
- For lines:

  ```
  if geom_type == 'LineString':
  ```

---

Example:

```
import glob, os
path = "H:/aOsmap/Miltkeyn/2012 ntfs/all/"
for layer in glob.glob(path + "*.dxf"):
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(layer, 'name', 'ogr')
    subLayers = vlayer.dataProvider().subLayers()
    for subLayer in subLayers:
        geom_type = subLayer.split(':')[-1]
        # Here we can add the if statement
        if geom_type == 'Point':
            uri = "%s|layername=entities|geometrytype=%s" % (layer, geom_type,)
            dfx_file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(layer))[0]
            layer_name = "%s - %s" % (dfx_file_name,geom_type,)
            sub_vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, layer_name, 'ogr')
            QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(sub_vlayer)
```

Comment: That works. Would I add linestring instead of point for the lines?

Comment: @PJLightning - Yes and be careful because it is case-sensitive. `LineString` :)

Comment: Information. The code given above is only applicable in versions of QGIS up to 2.18.
As of version 3.0, the code no longer works because QGIS have moved to a different version of Python.